# Different intents for different questions in Dialogflow

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Do we need to create different intents for different different questions? or  is there any way where we can put 4-5 different questions in the same intent ?
For example, I have

> Intent Comp-info

So, in Intent Comp-info I want to ask questions like

```
1) What is Computer?
2) What are Properties of Computer?
3) What are uses of Computer?
```

How can I ask this different questions in one single intent?
I have read about `input and output context` and I don't want to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intents represent different ways that users can ask or say the same sort of thing. So if these questions all *mean* the same thing, then you can certainly put them in the same Intent. Simply add multiple training phrases.

If, however, they mean different things (what Computer is may be different from how you use it, for example), then they should be in separate Intents.